# EntityManager persist() не сохраняет данные в БД ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, java-ee, jpa

При нажатии на кнопку `Register` должен добавляться новый пользователь в БД. Консоль выдает :

`INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: insert into public.customer (email, password, id) values (?, ?, ?)`

но при этом данные не записываются (никаких ошибок нету)

сервер -WildFly 13

**RegisterController** класс

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegisterController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Resource
private UserTransaction userTrans;

@Inject
private Customer customer;

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public String persist() {

    try {
        userTrans.begin();
        em.persist(customer);
        userTrans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return "register";
  }
}
```

**Customer** - класс :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(schema="public", name = "customer")
 @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
 public class Customer implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name="CUSTOMER_ID_GENERATOR", 
        sequenceName="seq_customer",
        schema="public",
        allocationSize=1,
        initialValue=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
generator="CUSTOMER_ID_GENERATOR")
private Long id;

private String email;

private String password;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "buyer")
private Set<Item> purchases;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "seller")
private Set<Item> offers;

public Customer() {
} ...
<геттеры и сеттеры>
```

**persistencе.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="online-shop">

    <class>com.java.model.Customer</class>
    <class>com.java.model.Item</class>

        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
             value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <!-- DB Dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> 
        <!-- create / create-drop / update -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
        <!-- Show SQL in  console -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Пытался добавлять `em.flush();` но это не помогло.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь/совет!

**data-source**

```
       <datasource jndi-name="java:/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS">
          <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresdb</connection-url>
          <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
          <driver>postgresql-42.2.4.jar</driver>
          <security>
              <user-name>postgres</user-name>
              <password>********</password>
          </security>
          <validation>
              <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
              <background-validation>true</background-validation>
              <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
          </validation>
      </datasource>
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос конфигурацию datasource

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  добавил

Comment: попробуйте `datasource jta="true"`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в настройках jta был автоматом выставлен в true, хоть и без упоминания в xml